# ECR security scan error: UNSUPPORTED_IMAGE while push image via Jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecr

I've tried to build an image via Jenkins, push it on AWS ecr and perform security scan, but faced an error: UNSUPPORTED_IMAGE

jenkins pipeline :

```
def customTag = 'thisiscustomTag'

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'docker' 
    }    
  stages {
    stage('Chekout') {
        steps {
            git branch: 'master',
            credentialsId: 'test-credentials',
            url: 'https://test.repo.git'
            }
        }
    stage('Building image') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withRegistry(
                    'https://000000000000.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
                    'ecr:eu-central-1:000000000000') {
                        myImage = docker.build(repo)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    stage('Pushing to ECR') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withRegistry(
                    'https://000000000000.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
                    'ecr:eu-central-1:000000000000') {
                        myImage.push(customTag)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Docker image was built on docker cloud agent based on https://hub.docker.com/r/bibinwilson/jenkins-slave/

Comment: Where is the definition for `customTag`?

Comment: at the top of the file, like 
def customTag = 'thisiscustomtag'